# How to handle a Future HttpResponse within an untyped Actor using pipe pattern

Tags: scala, akka

In my project, I have to write a rest client which will receive a HttpResponse as a future from a rest service. What I want is to log the status code of the response and in case of any exception, log that exception too. How can I achieve that using pipe pattern. PFB my code snippet:

```
class MetadataAggregator(implicit config: Config) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import context.system
  import akka.pattern.pipe

  implicit val exec = context.system.dispatcher

  val url = sys.env.getOrElse("URL", config.getString("conf.url"))

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MetadataEvent(event, phase, topic) =>
      val payload = captureMetadata(event, phase, topic)
      publishMetadata(payload)
    case _ => //Do nothing
  }

  
  def publishMetadata(payload: String) = {
    log.info(s"Metadata payload : $payload")
    val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(
      HttpRequest(
        HttpMethods.POST,
        uri = url,
        entity = HttpEntity(
          ContentTypes.`application/json`,
          payload
        )
      )
    )
  
    responseFuture.pipeTo(self)
  
  }

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case ex: RuntimeException =>
      log.error(s"${self.path} incurred an exception. $ex...")
      ex.printStackTrace()
      log.info("Resuming...")
      Resume
    case any: Any =>
      log.error(s"${self.path} stopping due to $any ...")
      any.printStackTrace()
      Stop
  }
}
```

Bdw, I can not use akka typed actor since the whole project is using untyped actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pipeTo` call is sending the `HttpResponse` to the actor, so you need to handle that in the `receive` method. But I would recommend creating a new message that includes the payload as well as the response, and send that to `self`. This allows you to describe the payload that caused the response.

The `HttpResponse` is being caught by `case _ =>` and ignored, so it is generally a good idea to log any unexpected messages so that this sort of thing is caught earlier.

---

Example code:

Create a new class for the result:

```
 case class PublishResult(payload: String, result: Try[HttpResponse])
```

In `publishMetadata`:

```
 val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(???)

 responseFuture.onComplete{ res =>
   self ! PublishResult(payload, res)
 }
```

In `receive` add this handler:

```
 case PublishResult(payload, res) =>
   res match {
     case Failure(e) =>
       log.warn("Request payload {} failed: {}", payload, e.getMessage)
     case Success(response) =>
       log.debug("Request succeeded")
   }
```

Comment: Thank you.. One question I have though, in case of any exception in the response, how to catch that in receive() handler.

Comment: Pass the full results of the `Future` in the result message and test for `Failure`. I've added some sample code for this.

Comment: Thanks Tim.. This looks awesome!! Also found out one article on this: https://blog.rockthejvm.com/pipe-pattern/  In this, it's saying that future.onComplete has some real drawback if we call it from an actor. Can you please take a look into that and let me know when we are calling responseFuture.onComplete() in the above code snippet, will it have the similar impact written in that article.

Comment: That article is saying that you shouldn't have any real code inside the `onComplete` part of the `Future` because it is called in a different thread, so you should only send messages so that the code is executed in the receive loop. This is what my code does. You could use `pipeToSelf` to implement this as they show if you like.

Comment: Got it Tim.. Thanks a lot..